# How can I disable the multiple repository feature in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: git, repository, visual-studio-2022

There used to be a setting to disable, Tools > Options > Environment > Preview Features and untick the New Git user experience. I've recently realised (with 17.6.0) that it has disappeared. I cannot find how to disable.

I want to disable the multiple repositories feature. These are the all  options I've got now.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update:**

With version 17.8.0 of Visual Studio 2022, you can now disable this as detailed below as well as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2022/release-notes#multi-repo-activation-setting-and-limit-increase).

---

**Answer prior to stable release:**

A popular feedback post on Microsoft's Developer Community was [answered](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/How-do-I-disable-the-multi-repository-fe/10370519#T-N10469967) by a Microsoft member that shows they are adding a way to disable this (it is now pending release to the stable version of Visual Studio 2022). However, Visual Studio 17.8 Preview 2 contains this feature now as described in [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-2022-17-8-preview-2-has-arrived/#multi-repo-activation-setting):

> In some workflows, it was important to control whether multi-repo was activated automatically. With a new setting you can keep your focus on an individual repository without seeing the multi-repository UI.
>
> [image: option to disable multiple repositories]

You should be able to find this option in Tools → Options → Source Control → Git Global Settings.

<sub>Note: this is currently only available in the *[preview version](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/preview/)* of Visual Studio 2022.  You can expect this to be pushed to the stable version in the near future.</sub>

Comment: 17.8 is now in production and I confirm I can disable multiple repos.